# GetStream feeds without enrichment

Tags: ios, getstream-io

Because of some requirements, we don't want to use the enrichment system where stream gets from its own collection the data objects.

In fact, we want to do it as the backend would do, using our own database, but directly from the client (because we don't use any database)

However, when retrieving the activities, we get the following: (iOS)

> JSON decoding error: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format..

We create activities in the way that, actor is User:UserID, Object is Object:PostID, Verb:ActionEnum.

That's all we do.. but one more time, we are facing issues on iOS SDK..

Why?

Comment: any code snippet would be useful

Comment: I will be able to provide some tomorrow but it is basically the documentation. Testing from REST approach is working like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone having this issue, it was coming from the iOS SDK itself... It turned out that, using the REST API from our client solved the issue, but we had to use the "extra" field part of Go to deliver our required data :)

Hope it helps